# AutoMapper: Number of child entities

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to convert the data of three tables into a flat ViewModel using AutoMapper.

Since I could not figure out how to setup the necessary AutoMapper configuration, I appreciate any information on how to solve this issue.

```
public class Category {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BankingAccountCategory> BankingAccountCategories { get; set; }
}

public class BankingAccountCategory {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BankingAccountId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual BankingAccount BankingAccount { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
}

public class Expense {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BankingAccountCategoryId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public virtual BankingAccountCategory BankingAccountCategory { get; set; }
}
```

My viewmodel:

```
public class CategoryViewModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfExpenses { get; set; }
}
```

On sql side, this query provides the result I want to have:

```
select cat.Id, cat.Title, cat.Description, count(ex.Id) as ExpenseCount from Category cat
  inner join BankingAccountCategory bac on bac.CategoryId = cat.Id                 
  left outer join Expense ex on ex.BankingAccountCategoryId = bac.Id
  group by cat.Id, cat.Title, cat.Description
```

My automapper configuration:

```
CreateMap<Category, CategoryViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.NumberOfExpenses, opt => opt.MapFrom(cat =>
        cat => BankingAccountCategory.Select(bac => bac.Expenses)));
```

The problem is that NumberOfExpenses is always 0 for all entries.

Comment: What about CreateMap<Category, CategoryViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.NumberOfExpenses, opt => opt.MapFrom(cat =>
        cat => BankingAccountCategory.Select(bac => bac.Expenses.Count())));

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev that would return an `IEnumerable<int>`, not `int` as per the type of `CategoryViewModel.NumberOfExpenses`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original configuration would have returned an `IEnumerable<ICollection<Expense>>`, not an `int` as desired.

Try this instead:

```
CreateMap<Category, CategoryViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.NumberOfExpenses,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(cat => BankingAccountCategories.Sum(bac => bac.Expenses.Count())));
```

Comment: Many Thanks. That was the solution! I did not realize that I have to add up all the entries :-)

Comment: @Felix yes, Automapper doesn't magically know what you want to do with your `IEnumerable<ICollection<Expense>>` :-)